# Make a class object a certain data type in java

Tags: java

Can I make a class object treated as another data type? I want to make an class, that can be read as a boolean object, when the object is created in a main class.
For example

```
public class ReturnValue {
    String one = "text";
    // some code that makes this class a boolean 'true'.
    }

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        returnValue object = new returnValue();
        if object
            System.out.println("the subclass is true.");  //so that it could print out.
    }
}
```

Comment: Take care about java naming convention. Class names should start with a uppercase letter

Comment: are you saying you want to check if an object is a subclass of another?

Comment: A class is a type, yes.

Comment: Your `if` statement is not even valid syntax, however, notwithstanding the fact that objects of type other than `Boolean` cannot be evaluated as booleans.

Comment: "_// some code that makes this class a boolean 'true'._" what do you means ?

Comment: @Jens Thank you!

Comment: @PaulHarris I want to make an object itself into another type...

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see!

Comment: @AxelH I was hoping there were some code, that would convert the subclass into a boolean value 'true'

Comment: define "_convert_" ...

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way is creating a method that will tell you if that object is "true" according to the properties:

```
public class returnValue {
    String one = "text";
    // some code that makes this class a boolean 'true'.
   public boolean isTrue() {
      return "text".equals(one); // just as example.
   }
}

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        returnValue object = new returnValue();
        if (object.isTrue())
            System.out.println("the subclass is true.");  //so that it could print out.
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL! I literally ended my answer with *"...you might even call `getValue` `isTrue` or something..."* Then posted, and saw you'd used that very name above. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't have the concept of automatically converting an object to a primitive value like a `boolean` (other than when the object is a `Boolean`, of course).

In your example, `Boolean` would be a reasonable choice (if it has to be an object type):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean object = Boolean.TRUE;
    if (object) {
        System.out.println("the subclass is true.");  //so that it could print out.
    }
}
```

If you wanted to roll your own, though, you'd have to provide an accessor method for the "boolean" value of the object:

```
class ReturnValue {
    private boolean value;

    ReturnValue(boolean v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public boolean getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

then

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReturnValue object = new ReturnValue(true);
    if (object.getValue()) {
        System.out.println("the subclass is true.");  //so that it could print out.
    }
}
```

You might even call `getValue` `isTrue` or similar.

Comment: I was hoping Java would provide converting an object to a primitive value. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @bellepark: Only for the predefined classes with corresponding primitives (`Boolean` => `boolean`, `Long` => `long`, etc.), not our own classes.